# I can´t use the grid properties correctly to create an specific layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create the layout that is shown in the image, but i can't do it in any way possible, i have tried using display: grid, grid-template-areas and almost all the grid properties, but i can't find the origin of the problem, when i try to set the grid-template-columns the full container moves to the left and when i try to use the grid-column or any other property to position the elements in the grid cell that i want it doesn´t do anything with all the elements within the container, it's like they are fixed in position maybe because of some other property that is colliding but i can´t make heads or tails of what can be.

[image: This is the layout i want to create]

[image: This is my actual layout]

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: var(--elements-padding);
  align-items: center;
}

.suite-logo-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.beta-access-button-1 {
  width: 11.375rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: solid black 1.5px;
  background-color: var(--clr-light-300);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-bold);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.beta-access-button-1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #172339;
  color: var(--clr-light-300);
}

.section-container {
  padding: var(--elements-secondary-padding);
}

.solution-word-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 9.467rem;
}

.curved-line-container {
  position: relative;
}

.curved-line-image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 9.6rem;
  width: 9.467rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.h1-styling {
  font-size: 2.375rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.53px;
  color: var(--clr-dark-400);
}

.title-span-styling {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--clr-dark-400);
}

.secondary-section-container {
  padding: var(--container-padding);
}

.primary-p-styling {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.09px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--clr-dark-300);
}

.beta-access-button-2-container {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
}

.beta-access-button-2 {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 3.813rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-bold);
  letter-spacing: -0.18px;
  color: var(--clr-light-300);
  background-color: var(--clr-dark-400);
}

.beta-access-button-2:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #a060ff, #cb30e3, #ffa84e);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-article-container {
  padding: var(--elements-padding);
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
}

.smartphone-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.third-section-container {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.big-word-styling {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--clr-dark-400);
}

.small-word-styling {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-regular);
  color: var(--clr-dark-300);
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.jeremy-image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -30rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.jeremy-large-image-mobile {
  width: 15.75rem;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 3;
}

.secondary-article-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: var(--container-padding);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 15rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-dark-400);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-top: 18rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.small-curved-line-image {
  width: 3.125rem;
}

.article-h2-styling {
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--clr-light-300);
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
}

.works-word-span {
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-bold);
}

.article-paragraph-styling {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
  color: var(--clr-light-400);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.09px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.article-h3-styling {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: var(--clr-light-300);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-bold);
}

.h3-word-styling {
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  color: var(--clr-light-400);
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-regular);
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--clr-light-400);
  margin-top: -1rem;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.footer-h2-styling {
  font-size: 0.983rem;
  font-weight: var(--ff-primary-regular);
  letter-spacing: 0.08px;
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
}

.logo-buttons-container {
  padding-top: var(--padding-top);
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header-container {
    padding-left: var(--tblt-padding);
    padding-right: var(--tblt-padding);
  }
  .grid-container {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 7rem;
    padding-left: var(--tblt-padding);
    padding-right: var(--tblt-padding);
  }
  .section-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    width: 30.438rem;
    padding-left: var(--tblt-padding);
    padding-right: var(--tblt-padding);
  }
  .grid-paragraph-container {
    padding-right: 8rem;
  }
  .primary-article-container {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }
  .smartphone-image-tblt {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .curved-line-image {
    left: 14rem;
    width: 14.449rem;
  }
  .h1-styling {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.78px;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
  .third-section-container {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: var(--tblt-padding);
    padding-right: var(--tblt-padding);
  }
  .secondary-article-container {
    padding-right: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
  }
  .article-div-container {
    padding-left: var(--tblt-padding);
    padding-right: var(--tblt-padding);
  }
  .suite-logo-container {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
  }
  .footer-container {
    height: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: -26.8rem;
    padding-top: 30rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .header-container {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding-left: var(--dkstp-padding);
    padding-right: var(--dkstp-padding);
  }
  .dsktp-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-right: var(--dkstp-padding);
    padding-left: var(--dkstp-padding);
  }
  .primary-article-container {
    padding-left: 16rem;
  }
  .smartphone-image-dsktp {
    height: 35rem;
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }
  .third-section-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    padding-right: 10rem;
  }
  .article-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-left: var(--dkstp-padding);
    padding-right: var(--dkstp-padding);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">
  <picture>
    <img class="suite-logo-image" src="./assets/logo.svg" alt="Suite logo">
  </picture>
  <button class="beta-access-button-1">Request Beta Access</button>
</header>
<div class="dsktp-grid-container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <section class="section-container">
      <picture class="curved-line-container">
        <img class="curved-line-image" src="./assets/pattern-curved-line-1.svg" alt="Black curved line">
      </picture>
      <h1 class="h1-styling">A <span class="title-span-styling">super <span class="s">solution</span></span> for your
        <span class="title-span-styling">business</span>.
      </h1>
      <div class="grid-paragraph-container">
        <p class="primary-p-styling">Our marketing and sales automations help you scale your outreach to get more leads for your company.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="beta-access-button-2-container">
        <button class="beta-access-button-2">Request Beta Access</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <article class="primary-article-container">
      <picture class="responsive-image">
        <img class="smartphone-image" src="./assets/image-hero-landscape@2x.png" alt="Smartphone in a colorful background">
        <img class="smartphone-image-tblt" src="./assets/image-hero-portrait@2x.png" alt="Smartphone in a tall colorful background">
        <img class="smartphone-image-dsktp" src="./assets/image-hero-portrait@2x.png" alt="">
      </picture>
    </article>
  </div>
  <section class="third-section-container">
    <p class="big-word-styling">2K+
      <span class="small-word-styling">Companies</span>
    </p>
    <p class="big-word-styling">8
      <span class="small-word-styling">Languages</span>
    </p>
    <p class="big-word-styling">
      1.2M <span class="small-word-styling">Leads</span></p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="article-grid-container">
  <div class="article-div-container">
    <picture class="jeremy-image-container">
      <img class="jeremy-large-image-mobile" src="./assets/image-jeremy-large@2x.png" alt="">
    </picture>
    <article class="secondary-article-container">
      <picture class="small-curved-line-container">
        <img class="small-curved-line-image" src="./assets/pattern-curved-line-2.svg" alt="">
      </picture>
      <h2 class="article-h2-styling">It just <span class="works-word-span">works.</span></h2>
      <p class="article-paragraph-styling">“I really like how it is an all-in-one solution that handle many of the tasks that you would normally need separate tools to do the same job. This thing is a miracle worker.”</p>
      <h3 class="article-h3-styling">Jeremy Robinson
        <span class="h3-word-styling">CMO, Fylo</span>
      </h3>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried creating different divs in the HTML to properly separate each grid child and then put the display: grid. But that didn´t work either, and almost any solution that you can think of, so my conclusion is that something is colliding with this particular container but i can't find what is it.